# Jquery Masonry extra space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to make a image grid system using JQUERY Masonry but i have a space problem.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ZGLWEE)** from codepen.io

If you visit the demo then please resize the page width<580px and then you can see there is a extra space how can i remove that extra space anyone can help me in this regard ?

I used this javascript for masonry selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-container').masonry({
   isFitWidth: true,
   itemSelector: '.user-image'
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
   $('.image-container').masonry('reload');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected.

My suggestion to you would be to remove the float on the image container. This IMO gives you the presentation you should expect from Masonry.

**Code:**

```
.image-container {
/* float:left; */
  position:relative;
  max-width:580px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left:3px;
}
```

Comment: Just for the ones who will do a copy past,

display: block; not disply ;)